# Authentication Error Software Center (can't install applications from software center)

Tags: virtualbox, software-center, chromebook

I am trying to install VirtualBox and whenever I go to install it I get this error:

[image]

I'm also running crouton on a Chromebook Dell Series 11 (Ubuntu XFCE)

Anyone know an easy way to fix? Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: if anyone could help that would be great.